# Why does ceiling in .NET return a Double and not an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, math

As explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx), Math.Ceiling returns: "The smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to a". But later it says: "Note that this method returns a Double type instead of an integral type." I'm just wondering why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because a double has a much bigger maximum value than an integer supports.

Asking for the ceiling on a `double` that has a value greater than [`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) (or even [`Int64.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx)) would not be possible if it returned an integer.

Comment: thought it was something like that. Thanks

Comment: @blgnklc: 10^-1 is 0.1, not 0.01 . . . but anyway, what does that have to do with Math.Ceiling?

Answer (score 2):

I think the purpose of that 'note' is to make sure people aren't led astray by the phrase 'integral value' into thinking that the return value is necessarily of an integer *type*. As other answers point out, not all integral *values* can be stored in integer-y *types*.

Comment: It would have been nice if they would link to the formal definition of integral :-)

Comment: @Anders: It would have been nice if they just said "returns a double type whose value is the smallest integer greater than or equal to a".  They're basically just using "integral value" to mean "integer" (which is perfectly correct, but I personally prefer to avoid this usage because the word "integral" makes people think of calculus and such.)

Comment: Yeah agree, that's much better. Why isn't it a wiki so that we can fix it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The *range* of the largest integer type is still much smaller than that of Double. So a lot of valid double values would not have a Ceiling().